# Replace character not work in DialogFlow after using time.split

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I´m trying to replace ',' to ':' in the 'setTime' result.

I already tried to create another variable and only after execute replace (). But it didn't work, "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error".

```
 function getTimeHandler(agent) {
       var setTime = agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].slice(0,5).split(':'); //gives me 21,32
       setTime = setTime.replace(',', ':');  
       agent.add(`${setTime}`); //error 503 WebHook
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that split will return Array of your splited values,

```
 var setTime = agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].slice(0,5).split(':');
```

This will return you Array `["03", "19"]`, [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)works on string not in Array. So you need to put

```js
function getTimeHandler(agent) {
    let setTime = new Date().toISOString()
        .split('T')[1]
        .slice(0, 5)
        .split(':');
    setTime = setTime.join(',').replace(',', ':');
    console.log(setTime)
   return setTime;
}
getTimeHandler()
```

in between them.

Comment: It worked perfect! Thanks. How can I enter my UTC-3:00?

Comment: I tried " new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}).toISOString() .... " But didint worked.

Comment: please check your Date before converting in another format

Comment: I tried to put after, but setTime() has not changed. Can u help me?

Comment: you can ask other question, or update this with your second query